# What the usage and role of "to be" in below sentence?

Tags: grammar, verbs, phrasal-verbs, to-infinitive, linking-verbs

What the usage and grammatical role of "to be" in below sentence?

> It rained this morning but it has turned out **to be** a lovely day.

What's the difference between the above sentence and below sentence when we delete it.

> It rained this morning but it has turned out **to** a lovely day.

Do this adjustment change the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: The second is not grammatical and is not used. Things turn out to be something. Or they turn out something. It has turned out [to be] a lovely day. He has turned out [to be] an excellent scholar. My dog has turned out [to be] a brute.

Comment: The second sentence is incorrect use.  You may be confusing the expression "turned into" with "turned out to".  "It rained this morning but it has turned into a lovely day" is perfectly good.